# getting specific columns from three tables

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I need to get specific columns from three tables through joins.every time it goes wrong.my code is

```
    $saf=mysqli_query($db , "select pod.mobile, tpaidamount.Aptdate, follow.cent, pdate, time from pod,tpaidamount, follow where tpaidamount.pid = follow.pid and pod.Customer Id = tpaidamount.pid and pod.Customer Id =follow.pid ");
$i=1;

while($sfg=mysqli_fetch_assoc($saf) or die(mysqli_error($db)))
;
?>

pod,tpaidamount,follow are tables and other coloumns
```

Getting error
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Id = tpaidamount.pid and pod.Customer Id =follow.pid' at line 1

Comment: You have a space in "pod.Customer Id = ", remove the space between Customer and Id

Comment: its that way in table

Comment: Use backticks around Customer Id if the space is in the column name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is it a typo? Is setfollowup.pid or follow.pid?

```
select pod.mobile, tpaidamount.Aptdate, follow.cent, <table>.pdate, <table>.time
from pod, tpaidamount, follow
where tpaidamount.pid = follow.pid 
and pod.`Customer Id` = tpaidamount.pid 
and pod.`Customer Id` = follow.pid
```

Comment: follow let  me check your solution

Comment: Hi, it could be because of the space in between Customer and Id. Try using `` for Customer Id. I've updated my suggested answer.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't Ever create columns names with spaces. The name: "pod.Customer Id" is a Bad attribute name, and you need to avoid use names like datatypes (or any SGBD reserved word) like: 'date', 'time', 'char', 'table', 'column'.... 
However, if you need to do it, try this SQL:

```
SELECT p.mobile
, t.Aptdate
, f.cent
, ???.pdate
, ???.`time`
FROM pod AS p
JOIN tpaidamount AS t ON o.`Customer Id` = t.pid 
JOIN follow AS f ON t.pid = f.pid ON p.`Customer Id` = f.pid
```

- Use alias for easy coding SQL queryes. Ex: table_name AS tn, table_a_name AS tan.
- !!! I sugest you to watch some basic SQL Lessons. 
  Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion on attributes.I changed it all.